# Extension to Test if NSString is Numeric in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, integer, nsstring

One can test if a String is numeric in swift using:

```
extension String  {
    var isNumber: Bool {
        return !isEmpty && rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil
    }
}
```

Is there a similar way to check if an `NSString` is numeric?  I have played around with the above but can't get anything to compile.

Comment: What about `(nsString as String).isNumber` ?

Comment: That should work calling from Swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to check if the length is greater than 0 and if the range location is equal to NSNotFound:

```
extension NSString  {
    var isNumber: Bool {
        return length > 0 && rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).location == NSNotFound
    }
}
```

---

```
("1" as NSString).isNumber  // true

("a" as NSString).isNumber // false
```

Comment: and you be able to call it from objective c as mystring.isNumber

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function in an extension

```
extension NSString  {
func isNumber() -> Bool {
    let str: String = self as String
    return Int(str) != nil || Double(str) != nil
    }
}
```

> ```
> let x: NSString = "32"
> x.isNumber() // true
> ```

Comment: OP is asking about `NSString` **Is there a similar way to check if an NSString is numeric?**

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's documentation :

A string is a series of characters, such as "Swift", that forms a collection. Strings in Swift are Unicode correct and locale insensitive, and are designed to be efficient. The String type bridges with the Objective-C class NSString and offers interoperability with C functions that works with strings.

So you can just type cast and use same method.